# Como posso criar um servidor para hospedagem de sites?

Tags: linux

Olá, estou estudando programação web e acabei tendo uma ideia para reaproveitar um computador antigo que está parado aqui em casa.

Fazendo algumas pesquisas sobre servidores, descobri que a melhor opção para mim é o Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS. Fiz o download e instalei na maquina em questão, pluguei ele ao cabo direto no roteador, fiz algumas configurações básicas de rede, instalei o LAMP e um servidor FTP atualmente ele só funciona na minha rede local.

Pelo fato de eu possuir um conhecimento muito escasso sobre redes e servidores, gostaria de saber:

1. É uma boa ideia utilizar um computador antigo desse jeito?
2. Caso for uma boa ideia, quais pacotes e aplicações devo instalar no meu "servidor" para poder hospedar sites e servidores de jogos com segurança?
3. Quais configurações são necessárias para que eu tenha segurança e não sofra uma invasão do meu "servidor" ou da minha rede pessoal, colocando em risco os dados dos outros dispositivos da minha casa?
4. Existe algum método de monitoramento para eu saber quem está conectado e se estou sendo invadido?
5. E qual configuração é necessária fazer no meu roteador para liberar acesso além da minha rede pessoal sem perder a segurança? (Já fiz algo parecido com um servidor de um jogo a muito tempo atrás, mas não sei se é seguro)

OBS: Não tenho intenções de hospedar sites profissionalmente, é apenas para estudo e também compartilhar meus sites e minhas aplicações com alguns amigos. Mesmo sendo apenas para teste, tenho a preocupação com a segurança da minha rede pessoal.

Caso alguém puder responder minhas duvidas, agradeço de todo coração o/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) É e não é. Acho interessante pq dessa forma vc vai estar estudando/aprendendo como funciona. O fato do computador ser antigo não impacta tanto, visto que existem muitas aplicações que podem rodar tranquilamente. Por outro lado não é tão interessante pq como vc mesmo disse, não possui muito conhecimento em redes e segurança, e pode acabar deixando sua rede local(pessoal) exposta. (Pesquise por hardening em servidores ubuntu)

2) O LAMP reúne uma série de ferramentas que podem ser usadas pra rodar uma aplicação básica em PHP por exemplo. Caso esse computador antigo seja 64 bits, pesquise sobre como rodar aplicações no Docker. Em relação ao que você vai ter que instalar no geral, depende de 'EM QUE LINGUAGEM' você vai desenvolver. Por exemplo se for um website usando Java, vc vai usar ferramentas diferentes( como apache tomcat) do que seria um projeto em  PHP.

3) Você tem que tomar cuidado para não subir nenhuma aplicação que contenha vulnerabilidade. Por exemplo um Apache < 2.2.34. [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42745) .Você teria que liberar por exemplo a porta 80,443 se for uma aplicação web. No mais eu sugiro você criar regras com UFW primeiro. Dessa forma vc pode liberar por exemplo somente um IP específico ..

4) Sim, na verdade existem vários. Você pode olhar os logs em tempo real. Para isso usa-se muito com o comando #tail -f /var/log/auth.log (apenas ex). Mas você pode usar ferramentas mais avançadas como IDS,IPS (ossec, zabbix, nagios).

5) Você vai ter que fazer o redirecionamento de portas (liberando apenas 443,8) se for aplicação web. Verifique também se o firmware do seu modem/roteador é seguro. Para isso basta jogar o modelo dele no google com algumas palavras chaves(security, exploit ..)

OBS: irei fazer um lab mais ou menos do que você ta querendo, caso queira entrar em contato me chama no telegram que a gente troca uma ideia. Lembrando que eu também estou estudando e tudo que eu te falei é com base no que já li e estudei até hoje .. 
Telegram => **@apolzek** 
Valeuu =D

Hardening -> Ubuntu
https://gist.github.com/lokhman/cc716d2e2d373dd696b2d9264c0287a3